# Substring function not yielding desired result

Tags: java, substring

I am currently working on the following program, trying to change an `ArrayList` of `Double` to a `String` one and then display the `substring(3,11)` of each element of the `String Array`.

Please see the following:

```
    ArrayList<Double> nums = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<String> strs = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (double i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
        nums.add(1/i);
}

    for (Double double1 : nums) {

        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(double1);
        strs.add(bd.toString());
    }

    for (String string : strs) {

        System.out.println(string.substring(3,11);
    }
```

But the issue is that every time I run this program, I get the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 11
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at AnotherTestClass.main(AnotherTestClass.java:28)
```

Comment: When you examined the variable called `string` in the debugger, what was its value?

Comment: What do you think `substring(3,11)` does?

Comment: Well the problem is some of the strings are not of length 11+. What exactly are you attempting to accomplish here, we might be able to help you towards a better solution.

Comment: `substring` is working as expected. Read the doc first to see how it behaves. Programmers don't write documentation for nothing.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for your help! David Coler's suggestion helped me resolve the issue.
I understood that it was my code that was wrong and not the substring function itself.
Using string.length()-1 as EndIndex helped hugely.
Thanks!

Comment: Then please vote my solution up.

Comment: I wish I could, and in fact I tried. But I don't have enough reputation points to be able to vote up anything. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string.substring(3,11);
```

the string you are attempting to substring is not that long.  change how you decide the substring variables. ie

```
if(string.length > 3)
    string.substring(3, (string.length -1));
```

Comment: The last index is exclusive, so to include the absolute last character, it would be `[3, string.length)` for the bounds.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is at line - System.out.println(string.substring(3,11));

The length of variable string is not more than 3 at any point in your code as per

```
for (double i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
  nums.add(1/i);
}
```

System.out.println(string.substring(3,11)) is failing. try to print the string value to understand

```
for (String string : strs) {
    System.out.println(string);
    System.out.println(string.substring(3,11);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. When I ran the code you have suggested I get the same error as before. But if I take out System.out.println(string.substring(3,11)) and leave System.out.println(string) I do get an output of all the strings in that array:
1
0.5
0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125
0.25
0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125
0.1666666666666666574148081281236954964697360992431640625
0.142857142857142849212692681248881854116916656494140625
0.125
0.111111111111111104943205418749130330979824066162109375
......................

Comment: `System.out` is not a debugger.